# Cryptic Haiku: Cornflakes are the bomb

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, poetry

> Bailing out on me?
>
> I'm sure it will be okay
>
> #Corn Flakes are the bomb

Looking for a particular event, and for a bonus, I would be impressed with a particular number

Hint 1:

> Not so Faust!

Hint 2:

> No corn or people were harmed in the making of this riddle. Good thing it was Winter!

Hint 3:

> I can think of more productive things to bomb....

I expect you to need to google, as this is not common knowledge. The riddle is figuring out what to google. Takes me back to to the good old Carmen Sandiego days....

Comment: If this hinges on little-known information, you should use the ‘‘knowledge’’ tag.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Things like "First puzzle, so be sure to help me get this right. (Tag suggestions, clarifications, etc)" should go in comments under your question, they shouldn't be *part* of the question. You should [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and [complete your profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22747/mizmor) for some easy badges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search query

> I searched "corn bomber"

Summary

> In 1970, a Convair F-106 Delta Dart landed in a farmer's filed in Montana

Line 1

> The pilot had ejected

Line 2

> The aircraft sustained minimal damage

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornfield_Bomber)

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome! +1

Comment: Excellent. Any guess on line 3? Definitely the most difficult/cryptic of the 3....